# Azure S2S vpn connection without IPSec

Tags: azure, vpn

I have azure subscription and have a home router (with no IPSec support) and I want to create a VPN tunnel. Need suggestion if I can still make a vpn tunnel to access on prem environment without IPSec configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For site-to-site VPN it's IPSec only.  If you are ok to establish a client VPN on your device instead then you have more options (OpenVPN, SSTP or IPSec) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways#planningtable

Comment: thanks for your answer actually yesterday I came across ZEROTIER or PFsense I think this would work like you suggest OpenVPN.